# How to train BERT with custom (raw text) domain-specific dataset using Huggingface?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I would like to train / fine-tune the BERT model with some own datasets which contain just raw data from a specific domain, similar to BioBERT. In the first step I just want to train BERT with this raw data, without fine-tuning with any specific NLP task. So, I want to build a base which I can potentially use for fine-tuning with annotated train data for specific tasks, such as NER, etc.
Is this possible in the way I plan to do it?

I tried to use the example scripts of Huggingface: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/language-modeling

I used the run_mlm script in the following way:

```
python run_mlm.py \
    --model_name_or_path bert-base-uncased\
    --train_file /path/to/text_file.txt \
    --do_train \
    --output_dir /out
```

I get some output but how can I evaluate the resulting model?
There are some intrinsic evaluation methods that I wanted to try but I failed, like word similarity or word analogy.

If you could help me with my approach I would be very thankful.

Comment: What kind of evaluation do you want to do?

Comment: I would like to evaluate my model in any manner that is possible with my raw data, not having any labeled test data.
I read something in [Revisiting Correlations between Intrinsic and Extrinsic Evaluations of Word Embeddings](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-01716-3_18) and thought I could e.g. compare the word similarity of some given words from my specific domain in general BERT model, and afterwards in my customized model and see if my model achieves better results. In a later stage I would fine-tune with (automatic generated?) training data on NER or similar tasks.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate a masked language model, there are two strategies:

- **intrinsic evaluations**, which you mention in your question. This is typically done with perplexity as a metric and is mentioned in papers like BERT.
- **extrinsic evaluations**: This is finetuning on benchmark sets like GLUE.

Although you ask for an intrinsic evaluation method, I would recommend to also perform some finetuning tasks. This can be GLUE, or your NER task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I looked up the perplexity metric but unfortunately it is not recommended for BERT: https://huggingface.co/transformers/perplexity.html
I found a paper about evaluating BERT, called BertScore, which has also a GitHub repository including the code. I think they use cosine similarity for the distance between word embeddings. If you are interested here is the link: https://github.com/Tiiiger/bert_score